# Send .dex file via post request android studio

Tags: file, android-studio, post, dex

For my own purposes, I want to send other app's dex file to a remote server and get the answer.

I've used answers that I found here. I tried to create a simple example at first, just to connect to the server and upload the dex file. So far I haven't managed to extract dex from other apps , so I thought of using a dex file I already have. 
As I've read, not common files should be stored either to "/res/raw" or "assets"
I tried many ways to load it as a **File** but none of them worked . The path I used in all cases were found in right click on file -> copy reference.

1. create a res folder under /raw and

   ```
   File f = new File("res/raw/filename.dex");
   ```
2. Create a new assets folder under /app

   ```
   File f = new File("filename.dex");
   ```
3. Create assets folder under /main

   ```
   File f = new File("main/assets/filename.dex");
   ```

   and so on.

The only way I managed to do so is by using InputStream

```
Inputstream in = getResources().openRawResources(R.raw.filename_without_dex)
```

but I couldn't cast it to File, so I dropped this solution.I want to have it as a **File** cause the following POST request must be a multipart/form.

In java, the way to "load" a file is straightforward. Why not in android ?

Comment: You can't open it as a file because it doesn't exist as a file on the filesystem. And the last part of your question makes no sense: "I want to have it as a File cause the following POST request must be a multipart/form.". There's no reason you can't do this by reading in the data from the InputStream.

Comment: @JesusFreke I see your point. I've tried this way [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)  which uses InputStream and I didn't manage to get it work. Could u give an example of proper use of InputStream to the getOutputStream()?

Comment: @JesusFreke The reason I ask, is cause I found many examples using `MultipartEntityBuilder` to create a multipart/form-data request which takes a `File` , but none for creating a multipart POST request using `HttpURLConnection` and `InputStream` classes

Comment: I'm not familiar with `HttpURLConnection` offhand, but after <5 minutes of searching, it looks like `MultipartEntityBuilder.addPart` accepts a `ContentBody`. The examples you saw most likely used a `FileBody`. However, you could also use an `InputStreamBody`, `StringBody` or `ByteArrayBody`, none of which require the use of a `File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A truly ugly, quick and dirty solution.
No error check or cleanup. 
But it works.

```
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    final String TAG = "GetDex";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getAppPaths(); // to list all packages

        String s = "/data/app/SoftKeyboard/SoftKeyboard.apk"; // a sample package
        byte[] b = getFile(s);
        byte[] dex = unzipDex(b, s);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("DEX size is %d", dex.length));
    }





List<String> getAppPaths() {
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages =  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
        Log.d(TAG, "Apk file path:" + packageInfo.sourceDir);
        paths.add(packageInfo.sourceDir);
    }

    return paths;
}


byte[] getFile(String filename) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        f.readFully(b);
        return b;
    } catch(IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public byte[] unzipDex(byte[] bytes, String filename) {
    try{
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filename);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while(ze!=null){
            String entryName = ze.getName();
            if(!entryName.equals("classes.dex")) {
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                continue;
            }

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(ze);

            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];

            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }

            buffer.flush();

            return buffer.toByteArray();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you @Roy. Although not the most suitable solution , it helped me understand